# Function not outputting code from array into div correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have am trying to have names outputted into lists using the following script:

```
var names = ["JakeP97", "Trishy", "Puffs", "Evilgenious", "Joeyc", "TheKid"];
var ballots = ["#book1", "#book2", "#book3", "#book4", "#book5", "#book6"];

function splitName(plName,ballotNum) {
    var halfplName = Math.round(plName.length / 2);
    var firstplName = plName.substr(0, halfplName);
    var lastplName = plName.substr(halfplName, plName.length);
    $(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_front').find('li:nth-child(2)').html(firstplName);
    $(ballotNum + 'ul.hardcover_back').find('li:nth-child(1)').html(lastplName);
}

for (i=0; i<ballots.length; i++) {
    splitName(names[i],ballots[i]);
}
```

Unfortunately it is not outputting the code, and I am not getting any syntax errors and the problem must be somewhere in my logic which I am not spotting.

I have a fiddle here which has the code written up for you all. 
[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yuaz35d/)

Let me know if there is any more information that I can provide to assist you in assisting me. Thank you

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/7yuaz35d/7/ You needed a space between `ballotNum` and `ul.hardcover...`

Comment: @ChrisG Please post this as an answer so I can upvote

Comment: It's a typo, you're probably bet to delete this as it won't help any future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `jquery` library at jsfiddle, and you need to add space between

```
ballotNum + ' ul.hardcover'
```

[result](https://jsfiddle.net/7yuaz35d/13/)

Hope helps,